# Ошибка объявления private static final String BASE_URL = getResources().getString(R.string.domin);

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь в статическом классе объявить

```
public class Constant {

//API Transactions
private static final String BASE_URL = getResources().getString(R.string.domin);

public static String GET_RECENT_PRODUCT = BASE_URL + "/api/api.php?get_recent";
public static final String GET_PRODUCT_ID = BASE_URL + "/api/api.php?product_id=";
public static final String GET_CATEGORY = BASE_URL + "/api/api.php?get_category";
public static final String GET_CATEGORY1 = BASE_URL + "/api/api.php?category1_id=";

}
```

Ошибка в `getResources()` Как мне её правильно объявить?

Comment: Ресурсы можо получить из контекста. В вашем случае, наверное, можно сделать Singleton для контекста в классе Application. Тогда получится что-то типа `MyApplication.getInstance().getResources()`

Comment: Интересно зачем базовый адрес размещать в ресурсах? Для разных языков используются разные сервера? Может просто прописать в коде как и остальные константы?

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете обратиться к ресурсам, не имея доступа к контексту.

Для того, чтобы вытащить что-либо из ресурсов, вам нужно передать в класс `Constant` `Context`. Тогда, обратившись к контексту, вы сможете вытащить ресурсы, которые вам нужны